# React checking multiple conditions to render a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, session-storage

I would like to check the sessionStorage and check another variable set by state before rendering a component. Basically if the user already acknowledges reading a message I would like to not show it anymore within the same session, so my code looks like this:

```
const addSession = (noteId: string) => {
  sessionStorage.setItem(noteId, noteId); 
}

const message = (props: ImessageProps) => {
  const [addedInSession, setAddedInSession] = useState(false); 
  return (
     <div>      
     {props.messages.map(m => {
        return (
        {!addedInSession && sessionStorage.getItem(noteId) && <MyComponent />}
         )
      })}
      </div>
  )}
```

However am having an error when I do the `!addedInSession` it's telling me ')' is expected. If I remove the !, then it will give an error on the first && saying ',' is expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove parenthesis for the return

Comment: Thanks. I did that but the whole code within the { } is disabled now. @WilliamWang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (
  {!addedInSession && sessionStorage.getItem(noteId) && <MyComponent />}
)
```

In this code, you're not inside any JSX, so you don't need to use curly brackets to escape back into regular javascript/typescript. So simply drop the curly brackets and you'll fix the syntax error:

```
return (
  !addedInSession && sessionStorage.getItem(noteId) && <MyComponent />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filter and chain a map would be the first thing I would do to conditionally render from an array, second you can place the bool in front of your map, as these values do not seem to change based on the message itself.

```js
{!addedInSession && sessionStorage.getItem(noteId) && props.messages.map(...
```

if you meant that noteId is a property on the message, I think following is what you are looking for

```js
{!addedInSession && props.messages.filter(m => sessionStorage.getItem(m.noteId)).map(...
```

assuming that `sessionStorage.getItem` will return undefined or null if not found